# Develop Android app on Android os

Tags: android, eclipse

Sorry if someone's already asked a similar question already, but I've been searching a lot without finding a solution.

Is there any way to develop Android apps on an actual device running the Android OS? For example, I have some plans to buy a tablet and it would be interesting to be able to run Eclipse (or something similar) and just make some apps. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah there are some Apps on the market, like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui...

Search for "IDE" (integrated development environment) on the Google Play Store.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: +1 for AIDE, it's really something special!

Comment: yeah, i use it for some time on a TEGRA3 device and it's faster than Eclipse with an hardware phone for testing... ;)

Comment: It only lacks SVN support so far, elsewise very good !

Comment: I use Git (!) with AGit and some own modifications on agit with pushing support...

Answer (score 3):

if you want programming for Android on your mobile device (for example in the travels), you can use an integrated development environment which runs on Android and allows to create native Android applications without the need to use the Android SDK on Windows or Linux,
You can download such app from google play like:

[Android java editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anjedi&hl=fr)

[JavaIDEdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.t_arn.JavaIDEdroid&feature=also_installed)

[DroidDevelop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.assoft.DroidDevelop&feature=also_installed)

[AIDE - Android Java IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&feature=related_apps)

Answer (score 2):

Try RFO BASIC!

Write programs on the Android Device in the BASIC! language.

http://laughton.com/basic/